# Extra data after end of document

Tags: sql, xml, database, plsql, xml-parsing

I have a problem inserting XML file. I have to create directory and passing from it. My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<a> 
    <date>20221011</date>
</a>    
<b>    
    <b1>    
        <field1>092010</field1>    
    </b1>    
    <b1>    
        <field1>093456</field1>
    </b1>
    ....
</b>
```

I want to import `<field1>`'s data into my table, not `<a>`'s. But of course there's an error for multiple roots. I want to remove or delete `<a>` tag or add `<a>` and `<b>` tags into a new root.

What should I do?

Comment: As you say, this is not a valid or well-formed XML document. A standard XML parser will have trouble parsing it and won't accept it. I see two courses of action: 1) Find an XML parser that allows malformed documents with multiple roots, or 2) preprocess the document to enclose it entirely in a single fake root `<?xml...?><fake><a></a><b></b></fake>` and therefore convert it to a valid XML document; then, it's easy to parse it and to filter it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried second option and added <fake> </fake> tags manually and it worked. But there's so many file like this so I have to create a procedure or function to add these tags. But I don't know how. If you know its syntax please help me, it took my 3 days and I couldn't figured it out. Thanks again!

Comment: It's just string manipulation: insert a second line with `<fake>` and then append `</fake>` at the end of the string. I'm no expert in PL/SQL but shouldn't be too difficult to do. In other languages the string manipulation should be trivial.

Comment: How do you receive the files?  Are they all in one directory?  What base OS?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are on a *nix OS, something like this sed command would work:

```
sed -i -e '2i<fake>' -e '$a</fake>' input.xml
```

Runs 2 commands on a file, insert `<fake>` as the second line, then append `</fake>` to the end of the named file.

CAVEAT: There is no checking first to see if you need the tags before adding them.

Take it to the next level by using xargs to run this on all xml files in the current directory:

```
ls *.xml | xargs -I{} sed -i -e '2i<fake>' -e '$a</fake>' {}
```

xargs runs the command once for every file output by `ls`.  The `{}` is replaced with the current filename in this case.